# Networking with Autopilot

Tags: networking, server, maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot

I've deployed openstack using Autopilot and was seamless, however, now that my private cloud is running, I am having difficulty with the networking.

I have 5 servers running within the internal network of 10.14.0.0/20.  I have the maas server connected to the public switch eth0 with 100.100.100.20 and internal switch with eth1 10.14.0.1.  I'm routing all traffic from the other physical machines through 10.14.0.1 with their eth0.  Each other machine is configured with eth1 being connected to the public switch and using the public fabric, but a undesignated ip.  The 'internal' cluster interface is managed and handles dhcp and dns, the public is unmanaged.  Each machine also has a seperate IPMI interface connected to the internal switch with static IPs assigned, 10.14.0.10/11/12/13 etc..

Everything has worked as I expected.  I've installed using Autopilot and set the proper public subnet for openvswitch.  Landscape, Horizon, etc.. are issued a 10.14.0.0 address within the static and dynamic ranges.  And I can connect to each of those services.  Where I don't understand what's happening is inside Horizon.  I have another network 'admin_net' that has been created using 10.10.0.0/16, where each VM is issued an IP in that subnet.  I can create and issue a floating ip from 100.100.100.20/28 and assign it to the instance, but I can't ping either the 10.10.0.0 address, or 100.100.100.20 address.

Is there any documentation for how autopilot configures openvswitch?  I get the concept, but there are quite a few settings between ports, routers, subnets inside Horizon, that I don't see a clear way of routing the traffic properly.

Answer (score 0):

A little more research and I found my answer.

By default, the only network that is created is the admin subnet, which creates a 10.10.0.0/16 network, which isn't usable by VMs, regardless of the floating IP.

The first step is to create a new tenant network. Under Networks>Network

Create network:
Network Name: vm-net
Check the 'create subnet' box

Subnet name: vm-subnet
Network Address: 192.168.1.0/24
IPV4
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
IP allocation pool: 192.168.1.2,192.168.1.254

Then create the router: Network > Routers
Name it and select your external network

Once it's created click on new router details, and click Interfaces
Add a new interface by naming it and selecting your vm-net subnet

I think that was it.  I'll update this answer if I discover more.

Comment: Why do you say the 10.10.0.0/16 network is not usable? Do you have that range elsewhere and there is a collision?

Comment: I suppose I made that assumption based on not being able to connect to it.   It could be routing, I was unable to access it from any of the physical machines on the internal network, nor was I able to connect to it when I assigned a floating IP.  Since it was called Admin_Net, it sounded like an internal services network.  Was it because I would be missing a router? @andreas

Comment: It should have worked using a floating ip.